# Do Motherboard Manufacturers refer max memory per MotherBoard or per Slot?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I am confused, When a Motherboard Manufacturer speaks about Max Memory, is it the maximum Memory the Motherboard supports or a Slot?

[image]

Comment: Your motherboard only supports 16GB or smaller modules

Comment: @Ramhound I would have to add that this MIGHT be incorrect, depending on the motherboard and the implementation by the OEM... It is possible that although there are 4 DIMM slots and a maximum capacity of 64GB, that it would operate perfectly well with a configuration of two 32GB memory modules.

Answer (score 1):

Max memory on a motherboard typically refers to the maxi amount the motherboard can handle. The only exceptions I've seen are on some multi socket server boards, where they specify max per slot.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum memory generally refers to the whole motherboard. If it is per slot it will usually specify that.